# Accessing a temporary adress using a Pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, memory, game-development

I am trying to fiddle around with CounterStrike in order to learn something about memory editing in C++. I used an offset dumper in order to obtain the static pointers and offsets that will lead to the temporary adresses of the dw_LocalPlayer, m_fFlags and dw_ForceJump. I am not using any memory editing classes like VAMemory.dll, just ReadProcessMemory. I found out that when the player is in the air, the value of m_fFlags is "256". When he is on the ground it is "257". However, I am not able to read these to values once I obtained a temporary adress. Here is the code:

```
// ConsoleApplication1.cpp : Definiert den Einstiegspunkt für die Konsolenanwendung.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <cstdint>

#define dwLocalPlayer 0xAB06EC
#define dwForceJump 0x4D6A684
#define fFlags 0x100

int main()
{

    HWND hwnd = FindWindowA(NULL, "Counter-Strike: Global Offensive");
    if (hwnd == NULL)
    {
        std::cout << "Error!" << std::endl;
        exit(-1);
        system("PAUSE");
    }

    else
    {
        DWORD pid = GetWindowThreadProcessId(hwnd, &pid);
        HANDLE pHandle = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, pid);


        DWORD tempadress;
        ReadProcessMemory(pHandle, (PBYTE*)dwLocalPlayer, &tempadress, sizeof(tempadress), NULL);

        DWORD fl_Onground = tempadress + fFlags;        

        std::cout << fl_Onground << "\n" << &fl_Onground << std::endl;
        system("PAUSE");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I would really appreciate some help and suggestions to the code since Im stuck on this since a few days. I am only trying to gain knowledge on C++ here, I do not want to code any cheats or whatnot...

Comment: `&fl_Onground` is the address of the variable `fl_Onground`. You want to look in the address that is `fl_Onground`'s value.

Comment: @molbdnilo So what I should do is `ReadProcessMemory` again once I added `tempadress + fFlags`?

Comment: Some remarks: you will not learn much of C++ that way, but only how to access memory of another process in Windows *whatever the language*. That being said, **you** may know what mean dwLocalPlayer and fFlags, but **I** don't. So how could I say whether it makes sense to add the value of fFlags to the value of tempAddress? I's sorry but your question is currently *unclear*.

Comment: Okay if I add those two values, one being a temporary adress and one being an offset of that adress, I should reach a specific place in memory which tells me if the player is in the air or not. The value that is stored inside this adress should be either 256 or 257. How do I read a value of an object using its memory adress? Hope this clears it up...

Answer (score 0):

You are not using the offsets correctly.  The offsets that are supplied by the dumper need to be added to other addresses, such as the base address of the module.

dwLocalPlayer is not a pointer to the local player, it's an offset.  You have to add it to the address of client_panorama.dll.

Secondly:
DWORD fl_Onground = tempadress + fFlags;

This gives you the address of fl_Onground but you never read it's value, your subsequent std::cout will print the address not the value.

Fixed code here:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <cstdint>
#include <TlHelp32.h>

#define dwLocalPlayer 0xD30B94
#define dwForceJump 0x51EE680
#define m_fFlags 0x104

uintptr_t GetModuleBaseAddress(DWORD procId, const wchar_t* modName)
{
    uintptr_t modBaseAddr = 0;
    HANDLE hSnap = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPMODULE | TH32CS_SNAPMODULE32, procId);
    if (hSnap != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        MODULEENTRY32 modEntry;
        modEntry.dwSize = sizeof(modEntry);
        if (Module32First(hSnap, &modEntry))
        {
            do
            {
                if (!_wcsicmp(modEntry.szModule, modName))
                {
                    modBaseAddr = (uintptr_t)modEntry.modBaseAddr;
                    break;
                }
            } while (Module32Next(hSnap, &modEntry));
        }
    }
    CloseHandle(hSnap);
    return modBaseAddr;
}

int main()
{
    HWND hwnd = FindWindowA(NULL, "Counter-Strike: Global Offensive");
    if (hwnd == NULL)
    {
        std::cout << "Error!\n" << std::endl;
        exit(-1);
        system("PAUSE");
    }

    else
    {
        DWORD pid = GetWindowThreadProcessId(hwnd, &pid);
        HANDLE pHandle = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, pid);

        uintptr_t dllBaseAddress = 0;
        dllBaseAddress = GetModuleBaseAddress(pid, L"client_panorama.dll");

        DWORD tempadress;
        ReadProcessMemory(pHandle, (BYTE*)(dllBaseAddress + dwLocalPlayer), &tempadress, sizeof(tempadress), NULL);

        BYTE fl_Onground = 0;
        ReadProcessMemory(pHandle, (BYTE*)(tempadress + m_fFlags), &fl_Onground, sizeof(fl_Onground), NULL);

        std::cout << fl_Onground << "\n" << &fl_Onground << std::endl;
        getchar();
    }

    return 0;
}
```